# Audio in a tool tip/hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, tooltip

I would like to include audio that will automatically play when the user scrolls over. I have not found a tooltip that will do this. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

(Note: The user will be warned about the audio before they have access to the page.)

***UPDATE***

I got this working thanks to Bakudan - хан ювиги. But is there a flash fall back available using Bakudan - хан ювиги's method? Thanks!

***UPDATE 2***

Using Bakudan - хан ювиги's recommended method for adding a flash fallback using swfobject leaves me a bit confused. My lack of javascript knowledge is where I get lost. Here is the code I am using for my audio:

```
    <script>

// Mouseover/ Click sound effect- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
// Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for full source code

var html5_audiotypes={ //define list of audio file extensions
"mp3": "audio/mpeg",
"ogg": "audio/ogg",
}

function createsoundbite(sound){
var html5audio=document.createElement('audio')
if (html5audio.canPlayType){ //check support for HTML5 audio
    for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++){
        var sourceel=document.createElement('source')
        sourceel.setAttribute('src', arguments[i])
        if (arguments[i].match(/\.(\w+)$/i))
            sourceel.setAttribute('type', html5_audiotypes[RegExp.$1])
        html5audio.appendChild(sourceel)
    }
    html5audio.load()
    html5audio.playclip=function(){
        html5audio.pause()
        html5audio.currentTime=0
        html5audio.play()
    }
    return html5audio
}
else{
    return {playclip:function(){throw new Error(
      "Your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio unfortunately")}}
}
}

//Initialize sound clips with 1 fallback file each:

var mouseoversound=createsoundbite(
   "/messages4u/2011/images/october/laugh.ogg",      
  "/messages4u/2011/images/october/laugh.mp3")

</script>
```

I changed the else to the flash instead of the error message. How do I change this using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation) to play the flash audio file? I am a bit lost by that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - Nope, not joking at all. It will be a special page and not for general access. Unless they choose to enter. Sounds kinda spooky...moans and screams and ghoslty noises for Halloween, don't cha know?

Comment: What's the problem? Don't you just bind a JS function to a mouseover event that plays the audio? Where are you running into trouble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/soundlink.shtml) is a good start. I`ve made a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sWgzy/). If the audio is a little bit longer, add stopclip function to the createsoundbite function and then add it to the [.mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/).

Edit:

To add flash change the else part. I'm very familiar with flash, but basically use one of the following:

- [create object](http://www.donatofurlani.it/category/programming/34/js_DOM_Flash_InternetExplorer) - "document.createElement("object");... etc"
- or which I think is better use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

Comment: Awesome! I have it working. - Is there a flash fallback available for anyone using IE8 or below?

Comment: One other question - How would I play multiple sounds on hover. IE This item has one sound on hover. This item has another sound on hover. I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I updated my question with one other question. If you would like I can make this another question separate from my original. But How do I add the flash to it using swfobject? I am a bit confused as how that is done.

Comment: @Lynda I'm not very familiar with flash, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that plays sound in older browsers and does not require flash:

```
var sound = document.createElement("audio");
if (!("src" in sound)) {
    sound = document.createElement("bgsound");
}
document.body.appendChild(sound);

function playSound(src) {
    sound.src = src;
    sound.play && sound.play();
}

...

playSound("/sounds/something.mp3");
```

**Edit:** Here's a version that uses `.hover()` to play the sound when the mouse hovers over your element:

```
$(function) {
    var sound = document.createElement("audio");
    if (!("src" in sound)) {
        sound = document.createElement("bgsound");
    }
    document.body.appendChild(sound);

    $(".playable").hover(function() {
        sound.src = this.soundFile;
        sound.play && sound.play();
    }, function() {
        sound.src = "";
    });
});
```

Set up your elements that you want to play a sound with a class of "playable" and custom attribute "soundFile" containing the source url for the sound file:

```
<span class="playable" soundFile="/sounds/something.mp3">Something</span>
<span class="playable" soundFile="/sounds/somethingElse.mp3">Something else</span>
```

Comment: I have tried to get this to work yet I am a bit confused. How do I trigger this on mouseover? Also how do I add multiple sounds per page?

Comment: @Lynda - Sorry for the delayed reply - clearly I'm too late to help you for this Halloween.  Nevertheless, I updated my answer with some code that will trigger the sound when the mouse is over the element.

Answer (score 0):

[soundmanager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)